# Hyper-V and physical switch trunk port SPAN/mirroring

Tags: hyper-v, mirroring

I'm new to the Hyper-V and trying to setup a lab. Here is my setup:
**Cisco switch** with a SPAN port (configured to mirror in/out, replicate the encapsulation, source port for the span is a trunk). I verified that I see all packets on the SPAN port
**Server** with Hyper-V VM that has two NICs. One is for general connectivity, the other is configured as a mirror destination. Vlan identification is disabled. Mapped to a virtual switch
**Virtual switch** is mapped to a dedicated server port connected to the Cisco SPAN port. OS sharing is allowed. VLAN identification is disabled. NDIS capture is enabled but NDIF also lists an errors in the window: "The Selected Extension is not operating correctly. Check the event logs for further information. If this is a non-Microsoft Extention, contact the vendor for further troubleshooting steps.
    Server NIC is configured as a Hyper-V source as explained here: https://cloudbase.it/hyper-v-promiscuous-mode/
    I can only see traffic from the server on the VM port. Nothing from the SPAN.

**Is it even possible to setup what I'm trying to achieve? If so, am I missing something?**

Thank you very much

SCREENSHOTS:
VM NIC:
[Pic: VM Nic configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCIPe.png)
VSwitch:
[Pic: VSwitch config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyHj.png)
[Pic: VSwitch config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zqYw.png)